# What activation function should I use for multi variable binary TRUE output?

Tags: neural-networks

I have a multi vairable binary target variable like this with multiple TRUE values.

```
    Y1  Y2  Y3  Y4
1   0   0   1   1
2   1   1   1   1
3   1   0   1   0
4   1   0   0   1
5   0   1   1   0
6   1   1   1   0
7   0   0   0   1
8   1   1   1   0
9   1   1   1   0
10  0   1   1   0
11  0   0   0   1
12  1   1   1   1
```

How should I prepare my output neural network such a way that I can predict multiple true variable?

I have tried using `softmax` activation function in the output layer for a multi variable single TRUE classification problems whose actual value is like this

```
Actual output value= [0, 0, 0, 1]
Predicted output value= [0.1,   0.2,    0.1,    0.6]
```

Then I take `argmax` of the predicted array which gives output `3` which result in `[0, 0, 0, 1]`. But what method should I follow for a classification  problem with multiple true  value output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply replace the `softmax` in the output layer with `sigmoid`, and train it with the [binary cross entropy](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/nnet.html#theano.tensor.nnet.nnet.binary_crossentropy) loss.